# TFS 2012 adding _1 when checking in database objects

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

Using the schema compare tool in TFS 2012, it pulls a bunch of SQL objects that says need to be added to the source control project, but they already exist in the source control project with the same name, everything is identical to what it says needs to be added. If I select Add to the item, it wants to add the item with an _1 on the end. How do I get it to recognize that the item already exists and doesn't need to be re-added?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I noticed that, while the objects were listed in Source Control explorer and were in my local Work space, they were not listed in the project in Solution Explorer. I was able to right click the object type I need and Add Existing to add the objects that were in source control that were not listed in Solution Explorer. An arduous process. I still have no idea how the objects in the project can get out of sync with what is in the solution.

Comment: at a guess someone merged an empty project file over the top of the project file with all the files in it. get your history on the sqlproj, get your finger of blame ready....only joking, anytime I look for someone to blame it always ends up being me :)

Comment: I know this is old, but this can happen if you import files using Schema Compare and then don't "Save All"